# intellij maven - org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies failed with error failed to copy full contents

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have maven project having multi modules. I do use intellij for building it, if I run project in serial order then it works fine. But when I do enable build independent module parallel with maven option **-T 4**, I lead to following error. Can someone help me to resolve this.

```
[INFO] Copying slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
[INFO] Copying httpclient-4.5.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\httpclient-4.5.6.jar
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (Copying dependencies into C:\idea\itrp/buildarea/deploy/opt/VRTSitrpdm/technology/lib) on project ibmsvc-globalmirror-common: Error copying artifact from C:\idea\itrp\m2localrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar: Failed to copy full contents from C:\idea\itrp\m2localrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (Copying dependencies into C:\idea\itrp/buildarea/deploy/opt/VRTSitrpdm/technology/lib) on project ibmsvc-globalmirror-common: Error copying artifact from C:\idea\itrp\m2localrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error copying artifact from C:\idea\itrp\m2localrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.copyFile(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromDependencies.CopyDependenciesMojo.copyArtifact(CopyDependenciesMojo.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromDependencies.CopyDependenciesMojo.doExecute(CopyDependenciesMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: **java.io.IOException: Failed to copy full contents from** C:\idea\itrp\m2localrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar to C:\idea\itrp\buildarea\deploy\opt\VRTSitrpdm\technology\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1054)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.copyFile(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:228)
    ... 16 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
```

Comment: First issue is: Why are you using `maven-dependency-plugin:copy`? Furthermore based on that your inter module dependencies are simply wrong which causes the issue...

Comment: As we know, need is to collect all required jars into a single lib folder from which I can start my app(jvm). Is there any alternative to this plugin?

Comment: Is there any known scenarios which I can look at?
Few modules copies the same artifacts to different lib dir, so that both app can start individually. Here in my case looks like two concurrent threads are trying to copy same artifacts.

Comment: I am also suspecting that maybe more than one modules are trying to copy same artifact in same target lib dir.

Comment: Best solution would be to make a separate module which uses the maven-assembly-plugin to produce a zip file with the appriopriate structure and do not forget to add the dependencies to this module..